# How to show a NSWindow (not fullscreen) and turn all the rest of the screen darker Xcode5 cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, shadow

I'm developing an app for MacOSX with Xcode5 which runs in fullscreen app

several times I need to show certain NSWindowControllers which are not in fullscreen as other NSWindowControllers

then I need to make my background darker for helping the user to focus on important information, I was thinking on finding a way to modificate NSWindowController's shadow but I could't find anything, I'm not sure how to achieve this:

current Window:

[image]

Desired effect

[image]

this is the code I use for opening my NSWindowController:

```
- (IBAction)showMyNSWindowController:(id)sender{

    if (!_myNSWindowController) {
        _myNSWindowController = [[MyNSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNSWindowController"];
        [_myNSWindowController.window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
    }

    [_myNSWindowController setDelegate:self];
    [_myNSWindowController initializeData];
    [_myNSWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I could make it work by doing this

AppDelegate.m

```
typedef void    * CGSConnection;
extern OSStatus CGSSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius(CGSConnection connection, NSInteger   windowNumber, int radius);
extern CGSConnection CGSDefaultConnectionForThread();

- (void)enableBlurForWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    [window setOpaque:NO];
    window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];

    CGSConnection connection = CGSDefaultConnectionForThread();
    CGSSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius(connection, [window windowNumber], 20);
}


- (IBAction)showMyNSWindowController:(id)sender{

    if (!_myNSWindowController) {
        _myNSWindowController = [[MyNSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNSWindowController"];
        [_myNSWindowController.window setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame] display:YES];
        [_myNSWindowController.window setOpaque:NO];
        [_myNSWindowController.window setBackgroundColor: [NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0.0
                                                                             saturation:0.0
                                                                             brightness:0.2
                                                                                  alpha:0.5]];
        [_myNSWindowController.window setMovable:FALSE];
        [self enableBlurForWindow:_myNSWindowController.window];

    }

    [_myNSWindowController setDelegate:self];
    [_myNSWindowController initializeData];
    [_myNSWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

I modified my NSWindowController by adding a NSView and putting everything inside like this:

[image]

this is the code for inicialization:

MyNSWindowController.m

```
-(void)initializeData{


    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [viewLayer setCornerRadius:5];
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
    [_containerView setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
    [_containerView setLayer:viewLayer];



    [_containerView setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(
                                        (NSWidth ([_parentView bounds]) - NSWidth([_containerView frame])) / 2,
                                        (NSHeight([_parentView bounds]) - NSHeight([_containerView frame]))/ 2)];
    [_containerView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin];
}
```

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is pretty much a "modal" window. you can try using a [modal window functionality](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow:) of `NSApplication`, but that may not be what you want because it blocks the main event loop in order to prevent interacting with things outside the modal window.

There is nothing stopping you from just making your window the size of the screen with that semi-transparent background and adding the current window content as a centered subview if this is more desirable.

[here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/05/presenting-mac-dialog-sheet-with-visual.html) is a nice example of similar behavior that you may find useful. It uses `CALayer` and `CIFilter` to achieve even more elaborate effects that a darkening (and its < 100 lines of code).

BTW `NSWindowController` doesnt have a "shadow" it is **not** a UI element (hence the "controller" portion of its name); you are thinking of `NSWindow`. That distinction may help you with farther searching.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and I could make it work, gonna put my code and results for future help